# Android Currency Input?

Tags: android

I have an editText that displays $0.00. When a user clicks on that, I want a numpad to come up. If they press 5, it should display $0.05, they press 3, it goes $0.53, they press 7 it goes $5.37, etc.

So far I have the editText displaying $0.00 and it brings up a numpad but you need to delete the numbers up to the $ sign and input the decimal yourself. I've had a few really complex ideas but I'm not sure I'm going about it the right way. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a variable `protected int curValue = 0;`

And set the editText each time a new number is pressed, 
`curValue *= 10; curValue += pressedNumber; editText.setText("$"+curValue/100.0f);`

(as long as you don't need real big numbers)

Comment: Don't assume all currencies do their fractions in hundredths, because there are a few that don't.

Comment: Ok, didn't know that. But still this solution covers the thread openers scenario.

Comment: "$" is a sign only used by a few currencies.  Make sure you localize it - see @Terrance's answer

Comment: Don't assume that floating point numbers will turn into strings the way you're expecting here.  You need to be explicit about formatting a string with the right numbers of digits.  (You could get something vaguely like 37.880000000000000000001 instead of what you're expecting.)

Answer (score 1):

Have you by chance taken a look at the android ref for currency?
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Currency.html

Comment: Don't forget to use this info to figure out what you should display for the currency symbol - don't hardcode "$"